# Contract Namespace — No Conflict and Why?

Tags: c#, wcf, namespaces

I am learning WCF and as part of the learning, i found out that the namespace for the contracts should match. I wrote a contract class (both client and host have their own copy) and made their namespace to not match but my code still works. I have provided code for my contract and host class and how client is calling the contract. could someone please advise where i am wrong?

Client Contract Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GeoLib.Client.Contracts
{
   [ServiceContract]
public interface IMessageContract
{
    [OperationContract (Name = "ShowMessage")]
    void ShowMsg(string message);
}
}
```

Host Contract Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GeoLib.WindowsHost.Contracts
{
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMessageContract
{
    [OperationContract]
    void ShowMessage(string message);
}
}
```

Calling Code in Client:

```
private void btnMakeCall_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ChannelFactory<IMessageContract> factory = new ChannelFactory<IMessageContract>("");
        IMessageContract proxy = factory.CreateChannel();

        proxy.ShowMsg(txtMessage.Text);

        factory.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

[Namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicecontractattribute.namespace(v=vs.110).aspx) in ServiceContracts or DataContracts are usually [used for versioning](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731060(v=vs.110).aspx) as they allow for two objects with the same name to exist in different namespaces.

It seems, however, that you haven't defined a Namespace for your Service.

Defining a namespace would be like:

```
[ServiceContract (Namespace="http://yourcompany.com/MyService/V1")]
public interface IMessageContract
{
    ...
}
```

If you later introduce a new version of your Service with new implementation and put it in a separate namespace such as:

```
[ServiceContract (Namespace="http://yourcompany.com/MyService/V2")]
    public interface IMessageContract
    {
        ...
    }
```

then you can keep the two services separated and have old clients calling  version1  and new clients calling version2

Comment: i am studying WCF course on Pluralsight by Miguel Castro and he advised the reason to use Namespace attribute like you advised to stop namespace conflicting when you are not sharing contracts and have host and client use their own contract.